# Assign pointer to variable in Golang

Tags: go

I am working in Golang, I have a Struct that contains some fields, one of them is a `time.Time` field to save the `Delete_At`so it can be null, basically I have defined it as:

```
type Contact struct {
     Delete_At *time.Time
}
```

So, with the pointer it can be null. Then, I have a method when this value is assigned, I have something like:

```
contact := Contact{}
contact.Deleted_At = time.Now()
```

But with it, I get:

```
cannot use time.Now() (type time.Time) as type *time.Time in assignment
```

I totally understand that is a bad assignment, but, how should I do it? how the conversion should be done?

Answer (score 7):

```
t := time.Now()
contact.Deleted_At = &t
```

And BTW, you should not use `_` in variable names. `DeletedAt` would be the recommended name.

Comment: uhhhh thank you @Flimzy I was also trying `&time.Now()` but now I see my error

Comment: you must use a var to get address memory of time.Now